# How do I create a macOS styled blue colored default button in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface

*emphasized text*I currently write Java applications on Mac OS X Mountain Lion and I want to get a button in Java which is Mac OS X style blue colored.

How do I make my button look like the Mac OS X style blue colored default button which is displayed in `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, you are looking for a default button.

```
JRootPane rootPane = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(button);
rootPane.setDefaultButton(button);
```

[image]

If you want to take a quick look at the result

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ButtonFrame extends JFrame
{
  JButton button;

  ButtonFrame(String title)
  {
    super(title);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    button = new JButton("OK");
    add(button);

    JRootPane rootPane = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(button);
    rootPane.setDefaultButton(button);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}

public class Sample
{
  public static void main ( String[] args )
  {
    ButtonFrame frame = new ButtonFrame("Demo");

    frame.setSize(200,80);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

and then

```
javac Sample.java
java -cp . Sample
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... And this is what I was looking for... And it helped me alot.

Comment: .oOo. Cool! Have fun with Java! .oOo.

Comment: Just a side note: Do not set icons for the button so that the blue color for the button would appear fine.